# sassで`color: value`利用時に警告が出る

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

### 前提

`app/assets/stylesheets/style.css.scss` に、以下の定義を書いています。

```
@each $color in red, purple, blue, green, yellow, orange {
  .c_#{$color} {
    color: $color;
  }
}
```

---

### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

スタイルは適用されるのですが、ターミナルに以下の警告が出ます。

> You probably don't mean to use the color value ' blue ' in interpolation here.
>   It may end up represented as #0000ff, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
>   Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "blue").
>   If you really want to use the color value here, use ' "" + $color '.

---

### 試したこと

警告に書いてある通り、以下のように修正しましたが、スタイルが適用されず、無効な値になります。

```
@each $color in red, purple, blue, green, yellow, orange {
  .c_#{$color} {
    "" + $color;
  }
}
```

どのように修正すればよいでしょうか。

---

### 補足情報 (OS, ツールのバージョンなど)

環境: Rails 4.2.10

Answer (score 0):

use ' "" + $color ' は "" + $color; にするように言ってるのではなく
color: などのプロパティを追加するよう警告しています。
なので下記のようにすればエラーにならないです。

```
@each $color in red, purple, blue, green, yellow, orange {
  .c_#{$color} {
    color: $color
  }
}
```